# why does my sticky position property not work

Tags: html, css, position, sticky

```
<div class="header">
        <a href="#" class="evanto-link">evanto</a><a href="#" id="evanto-link2">market</a>
        <a href="#"><button class="buynow-btn">Buy now</button></a>
        </div>

div.header{
  background-color: #0d0c09;
  padding: 10px;
  height: auto;
  position: sticky;
  margin: 0px;
  top: 0;
}
```

what can be the cause of the menu not sticking at the viewpoint, I have searched the internet but no success.

Comment: Do you have more to show us? I tried it on my end, works fine.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You must have at least some lines of content to scroll through to see the sticky effect. Your code works on my side. 
What do you try to achieve?